# Shell script generation command based on template

Tags: c++, bash, templates, shell, code-generation

**What I want to achieve**

- User would provide a command which would do remote execution. Command (protocol for remote execution) can be SSH/RSH... etc. So I want it to be part of a configuration file or a template file (assume parameters are fixed across protocol) like below sample -

template.cfg file (as configured by user):

```
ssh $ip $commandList
```

- I would generate a list of values in another data file which would contain the ip address and the command list. Like

  ```
  10.182.215.214|echo $UNAME
  10.251.142.142|echo $SHELLNAME
  ```
- I would like to have a script call it `driver.sh` which when executed, generates the actual script/scripts with the command from template to another execution script - `execute.sh`

**Questions**

1. How can I generate the script based on template/plugin (which can take liberty and provide the command)?
2. If the data is generated in an online application (C/C++), other than normal file based operation (read from the cfg file and update the `execute.sh`) is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
while IFS=\| read ip commandList
do  eval echo $(<template.cfg)
done <data >execute.sh
```

You may want to quote the variable expansions in the `data` file.

2.
Since you want the user-provided command to be part of a configuration file, I see no other way than to read from the cfg file; on the other hand, you may well directly execute the generated commands instead of writing them to an `execute.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

This almost looks as if you're trying to re-implement automated configuration tools like `puppet` or `chef`.  Beats the `ssh` loop.

Puppet contains a module called `facter`, which is used to report/collect all kinds of data about your remote systems.

All of these tools require some setup (public/private keypairs, software installation).
They both have the advantage of builtin logging - good for audits.